# Separate storage location for caches and index in IntelliJ idea

Tags: intellij-idea

The cache and index files in IntelliJ do produce a lot of space in incremental backups.

Since cache and index files can be regenerated, the question:

Is it possible to store these files in another filesystem location (e.g. /var/tmp/$username/$product/$version....)

If not, the other option is to simply exclude the directories from backup.
Is it save to exclude system/caches and system/index from the backup? Is it automatically recreated?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit bin/idea.properties in the IntelliJ IDEA installation directory and specify your preferred path as the value of the idea.system.path property.

It is also safe to exclude those files from the backup; they will be regenerated.